# Android FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver

Tags: android, firebase

In our application Crashlytics has detected a lot of crashes. All of them - on Android 8 and 9, App In Background - 99%. Suppose that users don't see that crash but it bothers our team. There are logs and a part of build.gradle

> ```
> > Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start receiver
> > com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver:
> > java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent {
> > act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=com.package.name
> > cmp=com.package.name/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService
> > (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{16f11ac u0a267 RCVR
> > bg:+4m21s760ms idle procs:1 seq(33,33,33)}
> ```

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=com.package.name cmp=com.package.name/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{16f11ac u0a267 RCVR bg:+4m21s760ms idle procs:1 seq(33,33,33)}
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1538)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1484)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:663)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:663)
       at android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService(WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:99)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzaak(Unknown Source:9)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzaaj(Unknown Source:72)
       at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.onReceive(Unknown Source:31)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3390)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1780)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

**app.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
```

...

```
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.17.1'

    implementation  ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'){
//        exclude module: "firebase-iid"
    }
```

There is a line "exclude module: "firebase-iid" which is my attempt to solve the problem (now there is no com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService in merged Manifest). But I know this approach is bad enough. Any ideas?